# Link two repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

Is it able to :

1. fork a seed repository named "A"
2. work and make changes on this forked repository "B"
3. Push commits on "B"
4. Pull changes from "A"

Answer (score 0):

Totally accepted. This is the way project in GitHub.com works. You can try it by yourself. Register 2 accounts on GitHub.com, user **Foo** and **Bar**

(1) Go to http://github.com , log in as user **Foo**.

(2) Create a brand-new repository called `repo_a`.

(3) Use an another web browser, go to http://github.com , log in as user **Bar**.

(4) Go to http://github.com/foo/repo_a , press button **Fork** at near top-right corner of web page.

(5) User **Foo**, push a commit has hashtag `xxxxxxx`.

(6) User **Far** fetch update from upstream repository (`repo_a`) like referenced link as below... and do like reference document.

Read more at: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/